# Selecting a range of variables in R

Tags: r, plyr

I need to summarize some data and I'm using the function `ddply` from `plyr` package. The dataset has 68 variables and I'm trying to take the mean of all variables, grouped by other two.

I'm trying to use the following code but it isn't working.

```
ddply(data, c("Var1", "Var2"), summarise, mean = mean(data$Var3 ~ data$Var68))
```

It shows me this message:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

What is the problem in that?

P.S.: Var1 is a `factor` with `6 levels`, Var2 is an `int`. All other variables are `num`.

Comment: `dplyr` is the successor to `plyr`, and is well-suited here. While you should really add enough data to the question to make it reproducible, it would be something like `data %>% group_by(Var1, Var2) %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[ , lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(Var1, Var2)]
```

Add bells and whistles to taste.

Comment: I didn't understand what is `.SD` in the `lapply` function

Comment: `.SD` is a `data.table`-specific temporary variable created within `[]`. Basically, it represents the whole dataset _within_ each `by` group. The mnemonic is **S**ubset of the **D**ata, since it can be manipulated with the `.SDcols` argument to represent a subset of columns; as it stands, it represents _all_ columns of `data`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a base R method, you can use `aggregate`.  Here is a working example:

```
aggregate(. ~ g1 + g2, data=df, FUN=mean)
  g1 g2          a         b         c
1  1  0  0.3163713 0.4030635 0.4926396
2  2  0 -0.8909029 0.4211550 0.3286698
3  1  1 -0.5466319 0.9146582 0.2588098
4  2  1 -0.6130626 0.2997645 0.5848791
```

This calculates the mean of three variables for two grouping variables. The same code will calculate the mean for 65 variables.

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10), b=runif(10),
                 g1=sample(1:2, 10, replace=T), g2=rep(0:1, 5))
```